# Is it possible to access text input's history with javascript?

Tags: javascript, browser-history

Firefox remembers what you have so far entered in a given text input and as soon as you start typing it suggests previous values matching what you have typed so far.

Is it possible to access this list via javascript?

Thanks.

Comment: @AakashM: I mean when the urls match, because otherwise it will be a security issue as you say.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Firefox remembers what you have so far
>   entered in a given text input and as
>   soon as you start typing it suggests
>   previous values matching what you have
>   typed so far.

This features is there with the browser itself.

> Is it possible to access this list via
>   javascript?

I am afraid, that's not possible

Comment: Certainly you've read about the restriction somewhere? Could you please say where?

Comment: @Majid: I know this is browser feature, you can not control that from javascript, for example, you can not change the settings of a browser via javascript because they are specific to browser, same is the case with this, it is the feature of browser, you can not control that from js but possibly there is something for that in the future.

Answer (score 1):

No that is not possible, that information is private to the user.

If it was possible, you could just put a textbox with the name "email" or "password" on a page, and start harvesting whatever people wrote in such textboxes on other sites.

Even if you limit the access to the same site, people doesn't always want to be associated with what they did earlier. If I for example accidentally made a search for something that happens to be urban slang for something else, I don't want "relevant ads" to follow me.

Comment: I don't think that would be the case. Because the browser keeps history on a per-domain basis. So emails you entered in box hosted on foo.com will NOT pop under a box hosted on bar.com. Basically, the data is what you have already submitted to whoever takes the form data.

Comment: @Majid: Even limited to the same domain, the information is still private to the user.